# WCF returns Bad Request on jquery ajax call

Tags: wcf, web-services, jquery

I have a WCF Service with one GET and one POST method. The GET works well.

The frontend is a simple HTML page which uses jquery ajax calls to GET and POST methods of the WCF.

The problem is that i get a Bad Request response. I have read all of the relative posts and i think that everything is in order, as far as i can tell.

Sources:

My contracts:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "schedule?week={week}",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        [Description("Return the food schedule; specify the dates to include.")]
        WeeklySchedule GetSchedule(int week);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="writeweek", Method = "POST", 
                    RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        [Description("Write or Update a week schedule via json data with POST")]
        int WriteWeek(string jsonwk);
```

I have a separate Data Access Layer which does the write/read in DB and works fine.

My page source regarding the ajax calls:

```
    function ajaxGetWeek(wk)
    {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            processData: false,
            url: 'http://appsrv01/food/svc/foodland.svc/schedule?week='+ wk,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                    GetWeekSucceeded(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

This works fine, it returns json format and i am able to parse it in my form.

POST ajax call that returns bad request:

```
function SubmitFood() {
        var features = new Object();    // Create empty javascript object
        features["weeknumber"] = currentWeek;
        $("#TheForm textarea").each(function() {           // Iterate over inputs
            features[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();  // Add each to features object
        });         
        var jsontxt = JSON.stringify(features);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://appsrv01/food/svc/foodland.svc/writeweek',
            data: jsontxt,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(postresult) {
                    WriteWeekSucceeded(postresult);
            },
            error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    }
```

The above returns something like:

```
{"weeknumber":24,"DishMon":"sdfadsf","DishTue":"asdfasd","DishWed":"fasdfa","DishThu":"sdfasdfas","DishFri":"dfasdf"}
```

i have put breakpoints in my VS solution but it dsoesnt even get to call the method.

my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FoodLandService.FoodLandService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6969/FoodLand"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="ContractsClass.IFoodLandService" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="Web"  />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and foodland.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="FoodLandService.FoodLandService"
     Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

My Service source:

```
public class FoodLandService : ContractsClass.IFoodLandService
{
    public WeeklySchedule GetSchedule(int week)
    {
        FoodClassDB fd = new FoodClassDB();
        return fd.ReadWeekDB(week);
    }

    public int WriteWeek(string jsonwk)
    {
        FoodClassDB fd = new FoodClassDB();
        return fd.WriteWeekDB(jsonwk);
    }
}
```

json is encoded fine and i cant find a reason for my error.

Comment: I think the basic problem is that your parameter for the POST operation is of type `string` but you're configuring the POST operation to consume json. It seems that 400 error is occurring because WCF can't deserialize the json your web app is sending into a string.

Comment: +1 for @SixtoSaez's comment above. e4rthdog - Why are you passing JSON instead of a string literal for the 'jsonwk' parameter?

Comment: ok, since i deserialize the json string later in my data access layer i should configure WCF to receive string. I tried to remove the requestformat but the problem is the same. What i have to do more to be able to receive string? Also in ajax jquery call should i change anything?